# Adding a function to a Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, function, distance

I want to write a function that let users input their zip code, and then it will pop up the distance from their zip code to mine.

I am not familiar with WordPress, is there any suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Development in WordPress is typically achieved by creating or modifying a theme.

Here is some good reading material:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development or https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/

This might be a good place to start.

Comment: This functionality sounds more suitable to a plugin though, although it could be a template.  SEE https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File

Answer (score 0):

You might find that in a plugin possibly a google maps related one (since that's basically what google does - enter address and offer distance & directions).